# Access VBA Reference Issue

Tags: ms-access, reference

I developed an Access Application on 2016. When the used runs it, he gets error and access closes.

But when I remove Excel object reference 16 and add it again, it runs perfectly.

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: use late bindings.. i.e. SET xlApp = createObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")

Comment: Well I am using the same Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(frmTest.txtImport, local:=True)

Comment: Issue is only when another user uses my application

Comment: Then u don't need excel reference. Remove completely

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thanks Krish